# Editing of a VLOOKUP formula that references a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

After inserting a VLOOKUP formula in a Google spreadsheet, where the array parameter references columns of a pivot table, how do I edit the formula again?

When I enter the formula, it just displays the value returned by the formula, and I can't seem to find a way to view or edit the original VLOOKUP formula.

Comment: Please share the docs with us (edit modus)

Comment: sorry, I can't data is sensitive.
however it must be something with my specific worksheet as when I tried to create a sample one showing the same issue it just worked.
maybe related to my having hebrew names to the sheets or the vlookup being across sheets, I will try to create a smaple.

Comment: I was finally able to replicate the issue on a test worksheet.
The missing part was that this happens only when the `array` parameter of the `VLOOKUP` formula references columns of a pivot table.

Comment: And Yet another UPDATE:
The same happens if you use =Indirect("B1") where B1 is inside a pivot table.

Comment: @pnuts - I don't see why you wouls say that its off-topic - nor why do you say that its un reproducable. however I did fail to accept the answer before and I have now corrected its. case closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue. I did a workaround which seems to work fine for me.

Instead of using something like

```
=vlookup(A2,BOM!A:B, 2,0)
```

I just added a +0 at the end as my lookup was returning an integer.

So when I put

```
=vlookup(A2,BOM!A:B, 2,0)+0
```

it works fine for me and my vlookup is now editable.

Also, if you already have a vlookup you may need to delete it and then reenter it.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> (when in cell) on the keyboard or double click in the cell itself.

See example file I created: [VLOOKUP](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGZZcE1yREQzWUoyeEdfeVRfOFFIZkE)

Comment: This works for other cells not the cells that have the vlookup inside them.

Comment: @epeleg: example added

Comment: As I already commented on the Q. I realize that this is not a general issue. but still it does happen to me. I will try to create an example that will demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I was finally able to replicate the issue on a test worksheet. The missing part was that this happens only when the array parameter of the VLOOKUP formula references columns of a pivot table. – epeleg just now

Answer (score 1):

Based on Prakashr's answer:

If you are looking up a number, then a workaround is to convert the result into a numerical value:

Instead of using something like

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,BOM!A:B, 2, 0)
```

Use

```
=VALUE(VLOOKUP(A2,BOM!A:B, 2, 0))
```

Also, if you already have a vlookup you may need to delete it and then re-enter it.